# Get SP & IDP metadata from database in place of file system

Tags: spring, database, single-sign-on, metadata, saml

Currently in Spring SAML 2.0, i get metadata from file system but now need to get from database so that no need to create war file again & again .
If anybody did the same , please help me on it

Comment: Why you need to create a war file again if you're reading the meta data from the system? If you're not worry about restarting the system then your code should pick up the meta data location/filename from some config file/database and then load the metadata.

Comment: @harry Currently i pick metadata file from local project directory like below - <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
<constructor-arg>
 <value type="java.io.File">classpath:security/idpmatadata.xml
 </value>
</constructor-arg>                                                                                                           Now need to pick metadata file from database or customer provide url for IDP metadata. So need suggestion which class should be use for the same . Thanks